# What should I say when my friend will have a new baby soon?

Tags: politeness

As titled. There are a ton of examples to congratulate newborns, however, is there anything similar before the birth of a new baby?

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks for the reply! I got a message from them for the news and I am trying hard to find a full sentence for the reply. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is customary to say “congratulations” to prospective parents from the moment they have officially *announced* their pregnancy. You don’t need to wait until the baby is born to say it.

As a sentence, and depending on your personal style, I would say something like: “Congratulations on your happy/wonderful news!” - or “That’s wonderful/exciting news - congratulations!”

In terms of politeness, your next step would be to ask after the expectant mother’s health and comfort, and to wish her well for the coming months.

A small tip: Try to be *sure* that she *is* expecting before you do say ‘congratulations’, to avoid any embarrassing comment on weight gain! And checking that it’s ‘official’ before congratulating her in front of coworkers or family would also be polite.

Comment: I up-voted you JUST for the "try to be sure that she is expecting before you do say ‘congratulations’, to avoid any embarrassing comment on weight gain!"

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I got a message from the parents saying that they are expecting a new baby so I assume this is a good signal to say congrats. However, I did not come up with a full sentence (instead of a word). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Definitely a good sign - I have added a suggested sentence as an edit.